# Custom lambda expression doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm making a lambda expression like this :

```
var property = typeof(Customer).GetProperty(inputArray[0], BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer));
var memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
var eq = Expression.Equal(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(value));
//Combining eq with ANDs and ORs
var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(eq, parameter);
// the lambda expression looks like this : {Param_0 => ((Param_0.NAME== "JASON") And (Param_0.NAME == "JASON"))}

var filteredCustomers = db.Customer.Where(lambdaExpression);
var list = filteredCustomers.ToList();
```

I can see that there are records whose name is JASON in the db. But list count is always zero. Can you tell me what the problem is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you just doing `db.Customer.Where(person => person.NAME == "Jason");`

Comment: @Dillanm because the parameter is variable. It can be something else. I'm using custom lambda expresssion for that.

Comment: If you try that lambda expression though, does *that* find the result?

Comment: I doubt that the code you've given creates a lambda expression with "And" in the middle...

Comment: @JonSkeet Mr. Skeet I don't know how to try lambda expression. The working code creates that lambda.

Comment: @jason I think he meant the expression I put above, if you try `db.Customer.Where(person => person.NAME == "JASON");` does it give you any results?

Comment: @Dillanm yes, I tested and it gives results.

Comment: So can you then change it to `db.Customer.Where(person => person.NAME == value);` (I assume `value` holds the name you're looking for) do you still get results?

Comment: @Dillanm I did that, and it worked as well.

Comment: @jason I believe that's your solution then right? You can rip out all of the code besides the last 2 lines and it'll do what you require.

Comment: @Dillanm but I want `NAME` parameter to be dynamic. It wouldn't be dynamic this way..

Comment: My mistake was that I wasn't trimming the value, so there was a backspace at the end of the string...

Comment: @jason You should really have specified that in the question, but glad you've got it sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future visitors looking at this post,OP has trimmed the value removing extra spaces.

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "p");
var memberExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Your_Property_Name");
var body = Expression.Equal(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(value.Trim()));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, param);
```